# spring jdbc + PlatformTransactionManager + spring data + theory

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-jdbc

I did start learn tool kit `spring jdbc`. Read some documentation about [transactions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic) 
in spring end their templates. Nevertheless some common things not clear to me.

1) **If we have `Spring Data` why always heard only about `Spring JDBC`**
Spring framework have some project like `Spring MVC`, `Spring Security` and etc.
 First i try to find `Spring JDBC` on home site of Spring, but do not found it. Instead of i found `Spring Data` project. After some research i found what `Spring Data` used `Spring JDBC` in `JDBC Extensions` sub-project and last have some `oracle` specific operation what interesting to me. And i realize what did not see or hear any use or see references in tutorials to `Spring Data`. It really something bad?

2) **Should I create new instance of JdbcTemplate every time**
Next was `JdbcTemplate`, useful template method. All docs replete with examples of code like

```
public class JdbcCorporateEventDao implements CorporateEventDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    // JDBC-backed implementations of the methods on the CorporateEventDao follow...
}
```

And they also write in docs

> Instances of the JdbcTemplate class are threadsafe once configured

This is misleading. Why in `setDataSource` method they create new instance if they can put `dataSource` in already created one or i misunderstood it?

3) **How can we use `TransactionTemplate` for writing sophisticated client logic?**
`TransactionTemplate` another one template what works with `TransactionStatus`. As I understand it can help me manage my transaction *but* how much help?
At the start of `execute` method of `TransactionTemplate` we have `transactionManager.getTransaction(this)`. At the end of `execute` method  we have line `this.transactionManager.commit(status)`. Therefore, how i understand it, all what i place in `doInTransaction` method will execute in single transaction. But how about execute other `DAO`s with same transaction in another methods? It constrains to be writing client with sophisticated logic. I mean all logic must be in one method? I thought it can not be true.
What i mean when say sophisticated logic. For example i have my own template method.

```
/*abstract class definition*/

public final void execute(){
    onPreExec();
    exec();
    onPostExec();
}

abstract void exec(); //client execute few DAOs methods

public void onPreExec(){}

public void onPostExec(){} //commit or rollback transaction in another method

/*other class members*/
```

4) **Is thread-safe to use "PTM", "TD", "TS"?**
Further i begin investigate what stand behind `this.transactionManager.commit(status)`. This represent to me `PlatformTransactionManager` and `TransactionDefinition`. How i understand, <del>at the moment when i start write this line of text</del>, this classes can help me achieve my goal in question #3. For example i can do like this:

```
/*abstract class definition*/

protected PlatformTransactionManager ptm;
protected TransactionDefinition td;
protected TransactionStatus ts;//TS with PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED

public final void execute(){
    onPreExec();
    exec();
    onPostExec();
}

abstract void exec(); //client execute few DAOs methods

public void onPreExec(){//start transaction
    ts=ptm.getTransaction(td);
}

public void onPostExec(){//end transaction
    if (exec.wasCompletedSuccessfully()){
       dao.markJobCompleted(); //do some for fix execution completeness
       ptm.commit(ts);
    } else {ptm.rollback(ts);}

}

/*other class members*/
```

At least this looks more convenient than `transactionTemplate.execute()` method for some cases. Although merely divided into several parts `transactionTemplate.execute()` method.

But still not clear it is thread-safe? i.e. can i use it and be sure that all inner call of `JDBC`s `callableStatment.execute()` methods from `jdbcTemplate` will refers to this and only to this transaction. And not see another transaction in other threads.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding JdbcTemplate:

jdbc template is provided by spring to interact with database. you can use simple JDBC code to connect database and perform operations but in this case you have to handle issues related connection closing etc. Spring jdbc template handles all these issues and the end user only need to use these api and execute operations.

regarding new JDBCTemplate(), i think this is an example only i.e. you need not to create jdbc template object in each class. you can create bean of it like data source or create BaseDAO class for this.

Comment: Thanks for answer on one question

Answer (score 0):

just one more thing, please go through [Spring Data Support](http://javabrains.koushik.org/p/spring-framework.html#data) videos. these are very good videos to learn basic of JDBC template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize that Spring has been around for 11 years now.  It's evolved.  There have been lots of projects that started as ancillary to Spring that have been folded into it.  Spring JDBC has been around since Rod Johnson first wrote it.  Spring Data is a recent development.